# SQLite3 returning empty array

Tags: javascript, typescript, sqlite, discord.js

My ticket system for a Discord bot in TypeScript works fine, but when I compiled it to JavaScript the SQLite3 queries aren't working anymore.

Code:

```
const [type, ticketId, userId] = interaction.customId.split("-");
console.log(ticketId);
db.all(`SELECT * FROM tickets WHERE ticketId=?`, [ticketId], async (err, rows) => {
    console.log(rows)
    if (type == "ticket.open") {
        ticketManager_1.TicketManager.onOpenButton(interaction, rows[0].ticketId, interaction.user.id);
    }
    else if (type == "ticket.close") {
        ticketManager_1.TicketManager.onCloseButton(interaction, rows[0].ticketId, interaction.user.id);
    }
});
```

Error:

```
ARjeXHw8EH <- this is the ticketId
undefined <- those are the rows
C:\Users\Mufaro\Desktop\ExoticRP\dist\events\interactionCreate.js:190
                    ticketManager_1.TicketManager.onOpenButton(interaction, rows[0].ticketId, interaction.user.id);
                                                                                ^

TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading '0')
    at Statement.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Mufaro\Desktop\ExoticRP\dist\events\interactionCreate.js:190:81)

Node.js v18.9.0
```

What am I doing wrong?